# Obtener ultimo email registrado - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Les hago una consulta, yo tengo una tabla de este tipo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Básicamente el usuario puede tener varios emails.

Lo que necesito hacer es traer todos los usuarios, sin repetirlos y que el email que traigo sea el ultimo registrado. Por ejemplo en el caso del usuario 1, deberia traerme el meial b@gmail.com unicamente

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ESTA TABLA que muestras esta relacionada con otra? esta tabla que nombre tiene?

Comment: @Alfredo Hola Alfredo! la tabla se llama "usuariosEmail" y esta relacionada a otra tabla donde estan los datos del usuario, pero eso no es importante!

Comment: IDCAMPO es un primaryKey?

Comment: Y si pruebas de este modo, haciendo un JOIN y aplicando un GROUP BY SELECT usuario.ID, usuario.nombre, usuarioemail.EMAIL
FROM usuario
JOIN usuariosemail
ON usuario.ID = usuarioemail.IDUSUARIO
GROUP BY usuario.nombre
ORDER BY usuarioemail.EMAIL DESC; obvio acomoda y coloca los nombres exactos de tus columnas

Comment: @pachecoton La unica pk es IDCAMPO

Comment: si la tabla "la tienes tu" significa que la base de datos es tuya, yo creo que sería mejor agregar la fecha del registro como parámetro, de esa forma puedes buscar el email registrado mas reciente acorde a la fecha y probablemente te surjan otras cosas que quieras hacer que esa fecha te puede responder como por ejemplo ver en que mes del año se registraron mas correos... cosas de ese estilo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juan , veo como posible solucion que selecciones el mayor campo para cada usuario y luego cruces ese valor obtenido con el email .

Por ejemplo esta seria la resolución que te planteo en MSSQL:

```
SELECT E.EMAIL 
FROM EMAIL E
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(E3.IDCAMPO) AS MAXCAMPO FROM EMAIL E3 GROUP BY E3.IDUSUARIO) E2
ON E2.MAXCAMPO = E.IDCAMPO
```

o más performante :

```
SELECT TOP 1 E.EMAIL 
FROM EMAIL E
ORDER BY E.ID_CAMPO DESC
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esta query:

```
 SELECT E.IDCAMPO,
        E.IDUSUARIO,
        E.EMAIL 
 FROM  (SELECT IDCAMPO,
               IDUSUARIO,
               EMAIL,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IDUSUARIO ORDER BY IDCAMPO DESC) AS ULTIMO 
               FROM EMAIL) E 
 WHERE ULTIMO = 1
```